# Debugging STM32 Nucleo with VSCode

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, stm32, mbed

I recently bought a [STMicroelectronics NUCLEO-F446ZE](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f446ze.html) and I am trying to set up a build&debug environment using visual studio code and make with the [mbed Framework](https://mbed.org/).

Things I have done:

- I have set up MSYS for make in Windows.
- I have downloaded the gcc-avr-none-eabi toolchain
- I have set up a mbed project with the mbed online tools and downloaded it for usage with make.
- I have updated the ST-Link firmware on my board
- I have installed the USB Driver for windows
- I have installed the ST-Link-Server
- I have installed the [cortex debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=marus25.cortex-debug) extension for vscode

This is the simple code I try to debug (for testing, it works just fine)

```
#include "mbed.h"

DigitalOut myled(LED1);

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        myled = 1; // LED is ON
        wait(0.2); // 200 ms
        myled = 0; // LED is OFF
        wait(0.2); // 200 ms
        myled = 1; // LED is ON
        wait(0.2); // 200 ms
        myled = 0; // LED is ON
        wait(1.0); // 1 sec
    }
}
```

And after I did all of that almost everything worked! I can build, I can flash and I can even debug, BUT the cpp symbols seem to be mismatched.

Some of my breakpoints are not hit at all and with others the program stops one line above or under the wanted line. I cannot read any variables in the "watch" panel and have no disassembly information.

[Here is a link to a gif](https://gyazo.com/bc1aa0b5a17f309c16f07a7ed4453a0c) that shows both: One breakpoint is ignored, the other stops at the wrong line.

Also if I press F10 to step over an instruction the highlighted line sometimes moves backwards.

I really don't know how to fix this annoying behavior.
I *think* that I had similar problems debugging 'regular' c++ code running locally on my laptop (with MingW). So maybe this does have nothing to do with embedded development, but is a general c++ problem in vscode?

Edit:

When the execution stops in a wrong line the debug console actually says:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at ../main.cpp:12
12          wait(0.2); // 200 ms
```

But I set a breakpoint in line 11 in the editor, not line 12. :(

Comment: Change the optimisation level to zero.  then it will stop where you want. Otherwise not all lines of core are explicity present (in the form you see in the source code) in the compiled executable

Comment: @P__J__ Thanks, real noob here when it comes to c++... The optimisation level of what? Of gcc or g++ or during the linking? Or something completely different?

Comment: gcc & g++ have the same options.

Comment: @P__J__ thanks a friend of mine helped me out. The mbed online tool used -Os and I switched that to -O0.

Also I changed -g1 to -g so that I can see whats inside my variables during debugging. Thank you for your help!

Comment: actualy better to g. But it is not related to the variables. Variables can be optimized out.

Comment: Is there an option to choose a profile when downloading for Make?  From the CLI, you can pass --profile debug to get debug profile, which will turn off optimization as other commenters have suggested